# Postgresql/PGadmin3 - Export to multiple tabs in XLSX file

Tags: postgresql, xlsx, pgadmin

Is it possible to run multiple PostgreSQL queries, and using pgadmin3 have them each export to a separate tab on a XLSX file?

On those same lines, is it possible to run one PostgresQL query that exports to multiple tabs based on some criteria?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, CSV files can only have 1 tab.

Comment: You are correct - Edited my post to show.

Comment: I don't think that is possible either. But, PostgreSQL supports a number of languages for writting procedures which can accomplish what you are looking for see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/external-pl.html

Comment: I don't think pgAdmin can do that. Maybe one of the other tools listed unter https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools can do that.

Comment: If you found a solution, I'm interested to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an external tool for this. PostgreSQL knows nothing about the XLSX format, nor about OpenDocument or any of that.

I suggest writing a script that exports a bunch of individual CSV files with `copy`. Then using an external tool to convert them to xlsx and assemble them into sheets in the document.

It's possible that ETL tools like CloverETL, Pentaho Kettle, or Talend Studio may do what you want too. I haven't checked this specific functionality.